# What type of intent filters are needed for NFC Type 2 tags?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter

I'm currently building an NFC writer application and at the moment I am just playing around with the basics of NFC and reading/writing with tags.

The types of tags I have are NFC Forum Type 2 Tags with NTAG216 chips.

I am trying to get my application to start when the tags are read while the application is closed. I can get this to work with other NFC tag types but when I scan these tags I get the default 'New tag collected' screen.

Currently my app has intent filters to open with every type of NFC Intent and every type of NFC Tech.

In my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
     android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_list" />
```

When the app is launched it should just simply change the text in a text view (works with other NFC tags):

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)){
    TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    mainText.setText("App Launched by NFC");
    vibrate();
}
```

My nfc_tech_list file:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
</tech-list>
```

Could it be the fact that there is no data on the tag?
Or is it something to do with the tags themselves?

Any help is appreciated.

Update:
Turns out the tech compatible on my tags are as follows

- NfcA
- MiFare UltraLight
- Ndef